# Override DataGrid Foreground

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to override the foreground color of the selected DataGrid Line in my WPF DataGrid.

Foreach column the foreground is set in the definition.

```
<DataGrid.Columns><DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Black"/>
```

I have created a new DataGridCell style. But this does only work for columns for which a foreground color is not set.

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="BlueViolet" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, there is something called the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx). Please follow the link for the full details, but in short, `DependencyProperty`s can be updated from many different sources: `Animation`s, Style`s, code behind, etc. There is a list (in the linked page) that orders all of these sources from most important to least important.

More important sources have precedence over less important sources and can change the values that the less important sources set.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Black" />
```

In the above code, the `Foreground` property is set inline, so it has the precedence of a *Local value*, which is higher than that of a *Style trigger*. Therefore, your `Trigger Setter` is not able to alter the 'more important' value that you set inline.

The solution is simple... set your initial value using a source with a lower precedence, such as a *Style Setter*. However, now you have the problem that the `DataGridTextColumn` is not a regular `FrameworkElement` and so does not have a `Style` property. Luckily, there is a `CellStyle` property that you should be able to use:

```
<DataGridTextColumn ... >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: That link will be very useful for me in the future, thanks. But I need to add, that in order to work you need obv. to add  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}" to the header.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I doubt that you *need* to use the `BasedOn` property too, as the `TargetType` will already point to the default `Style`.

Comment: Hi @Sheridan, quick enhancment question: why is this first line working and the second not? (Creation is completly in code): column.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.ForegroundProperty,  Brushes.Red));
            column.CellStyle = cellStyle;

Comment: Forget it, my error was that I was setting a element style before which overrides the cellstyle.